# Building website like askmeflash.com

Tags: php, html

I am new to html world . I build all our websites with flex . I have concepts of html ,php ,java(architect) ,Mysql( Oracle DBA)  Looking for your help to build website like askmeflash.com . I mean

Are there any available frameworks I can use to build like that? 
What should I learn to build website like this?
What tools I have to use ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Regards

Bujji

Comment: Look, a Flash-only version of SO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bujji, there's nothing magical about askmeflash.com.  It's a straightforward site that handles information in, information out with a user management system as any simple web application does.  I'd recommend reading a book about building CMS's for the basic concepts, because in essence it's the same thing.  This is the one that got me started way back when:  http://www.sitepoint.com/books/phpmysql4/

As for frameworks, if you're going PHP/MySQL as you've mentioned, the two frameworks that seem to dominate the landscape today are Zend Framework (framework.zend.com) and Code Igniter (codeigniter.com)  Personally, I wouldn't attempt either without a basic knowledge of the ins-and-outs of PHP and OO concepts.  Zend especially is very powerful but can get confusing in the beginning....

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation . I was looking at joomla , Drupal and other forums software . Thought I can build this website with the help of them easily ( with customization) . But now got the fundamentals . I used AMFPHP for my flex development and have an idea . I am going to get that book  you mentioned today and the Zend framework  . Thanks for your help . May be last question can I use drupal or Joomla or any forum software and build website like askmeflash.com easily ? I mean instead of building from scratch . Can I take advantage of any one of them ?